# Inequality of determinant and product of diagonal elements of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Is is true that the det$ A$(which is the product of eigenvalues) is smaller or equal to the product of diagonal elements of $A$ ?

I could not prove it, and not even sure if the inequality above is true.

Comment: It is true. You should try induction. You mean *diagonal elements*, I think, not *diagonals* above.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Let $A=LL^\ast$ be a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). Then $\det(A)$ is the product of the squared diagonal elements of $L$, while the product of the diagonal elements of $A$ is the product of the squared norms of the rows of $L$. Since the norm of each row of a matrix is necessarily greater than or equal to the magnitude of the diagonal element on that row, the conclusion follows.